# Has anyone used the Salesforce DX CLI "shape" command?

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, scratch-org, shape-org

In the Salesforce Winter '19 release, the Salesforce CLI recently was updated with a command with a CLI call: sfdx force:org:shape.

```
 force:org:shape:create     create a snapshot of org edition, features, and licenses
 force:org:shape:delete     delete all org shapes for a target org
 force:org:shape:list       list all org shapes you’ve created
 force:org:snapshot:create  snapshot a scratch org
 force:org:snapshot:delete  delete a scratch org snapshot
 force:org:snapshot:get     get details about a scratch org snapshot
 force:org:snapshot:list    list scratch org snapshots `enter code here`
```

Has anyone used this feature? If so, has this feature allowed you to successfully take a snapshot of your production/sandbox and deploy it to a scratch org in order to develop on a scratch that practically mirrors the environment of your choice?

Thanks in advance for your answers and advice!

Answer (score 4):

Its a pilot feature and you will need to work with salesforce to get this enabled for your Devhub .

Org Shape is different than Org Snapshot feature and both of these are in pilot.

You can get more help on [trailblazer community](https://success.salesforce.com/loginswitcher?startURL=%2F_ui%2Fcore%2Fchatter%2Fgroups%2FGroupProfilePage%3Fg%3D0F93A0000009TPk) to get started .

Org Shape - Take a snapshot from the Sandbox/Production to match licenses , features and edition and use that.

Org Snapshot - Configure a scratch org and then use that to create subsequent orgs .

Answer (score 0):

I have been using the Org Shape feature successfully for nearly a year

It is the only way we can feasibly use scratch orgs in a reliable manner. On every release cycle, it seems that my scratch org spin-up process hits the snag that "the shape has expired" [SH-0003  error in the CLI](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_error_codes.htm) but it only takes a few seconds to delete and recreate the shape. Then I'm going again

I wish this feature took care of installing my plugins, but it is very useful nevertheless.